# Number of Injury claims per month

Tags: probability, combinatorics, statistics

The number of injury claims per month is given by $N$ where

$\\$
 $ 
P(N=n) =\dfrac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)}
$

where $0 \leq n$

Determine the probability of at least one claim during a particular month given that there have been at most four claims during that month.

I have this so far: You have 5 conditions, the 1st is no claims in a  month, the 2nd is the 1 claim and so on. I've deicded that the easiest way to do this is to use the compliement that is, $PR($No claim| at most 4 claims$)$

Condition 1: $PR\;(No\; claim\; | \;No\; claim)=\dfrac{1}{4}$

Condition 2: $PR\;(No \; claim\; | \;1 \; claim)= \dfrac{1}{12}$

Condition 3: $PR\;(No \; claim \; | \; 2\; claims)= \dfrac{1}{24}    $

Condition 4: $PR\;(No \; claim \; | \; 3 \; claims)= \dfrac{1}{40}$

Condition 5: $PR\;(No \; claim \; | \; 4 \; claims) = \dfrac{1}{60}$

The sum of the probabilities will be my demoniator. I dont think I am going about this the right way since the answer is now here near what I got.

Comment: This is a SOA practice problem. :)  I'd be happy to spoil it for you, but are you sure you can't figure it out from the solutions they provide?

Comment: Oh yes I found it, it was actually quite simple. I overlooked the definition of conditional probability.

Answer (score 1):

I'll enumerate the mass function:

$$P(n) = 
\begin{cases}
  \frac{1}{2} \text{ if } n = 0\\
  \frac{1}{6} \text{ if } n = 1\\
  \frac{1}{12}\text{ if } n = 2\\
  \frac{1}{20}\text{ if } n = 3\\
  \frac{1}{30}\text{ if } n = 4\\
\end{cases}
$$

This is a sufficiently "deep" enough enumeration, since, recalling the definition of the conditional probability,

$$
 P(X\geq 1 | X \leq 4) = \frac{P(1 \leq X \leq 4)}{P(X\leq 4)}\\
  = \frac{ \frac{1}{6} + \frac{1}{12} + \frac{1}{20} + \frac{1}{30} }{ \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{6} + \frac{1}{12} + \frac{1}{20} + \frac{1}{30} }
$$